# SharpSNMPLib BulkWalkAsync Method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sharp-snmp

Looking for the `BulkWalkAsync` method.  If I do a Google search I come across some code from about six years ago (based on the copyright).  It looks like a static method accessible as `Messenger.BulkWalkAsync` but when I peruse the code through VS I don't see it.  I can't find any documentation saying it was removed, but it's not there.

`BulkWalkAsync` is really what I need.  Or if someone has an alternative for me.  Writing a data collector that grabs MAC addresses from Cisco equipment (v2c, using community string indexing).  There are 300+ VLANs and two devices in particular are taking about one second to respond to each VLAN, so it's taking 5+ minutes to collect.

Using VS 2015, .Net 4.5.1, and #SNMP 9.0.1 installed through NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

The async methods are only coming in 9.0.2, which is currently in RC. Will soon publish the RTM build in a few weeks.